# How to differentiate both sides with an independent variable if one doesn't have a formula?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have an equation similar to the following:
$$\frac{a}{b} = c$$

Now I want to differentiate both sides with respect to an independent variable:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} (\frac{a}{b}) = \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(c)$$

I have the data that represents $a/b$ and $c$ and how it changes with $x$ but I do not have a formula. Now if I try to differentiate like that I would get $0$. Right? Because the derivative of a constant is equals to zero. Is there a way to calculate the derivatives when you do not have an explicit formula?

Note: If this question sounds stupid, I am sorry because I am very new to calculus.

Comment: What is the *actual* equation that you have?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 It is very similar to the one given with different variable names.

Comment: This seems like an example of the XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the intent is that $a,b,c$ depend on $x$, then what you have as a result is
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{dc(x)}{dx} &= \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{a(x)}{b(x)} \right) \\
c'(x) &= \frac{a'(x) b(x) - b'(x) a(x)}{b^2(x)}
\end{split}
$$

This relies on the [Quotient Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule)

**UPDATE** If as mentioned in the comments, $b$ is not a function of $x$, we assume $b$ is a constant, and so $b'(x) = 0$, so the above result simplies to
$$
c'(x) = \frac{a'(x) b(x)}{b^2(x)} = \frac{a'(x)}{b(x)} \quad \text{where } b(x) \ne 0
$$

Comment: $b$ does not depend on $x$. It is not a function of $x$. Now what?

Comment: @Anonymous see update

Comment: That still doesn't solves the problem. $a(x)$ and $c(x)$ are not explicitly defined. I know what is the value of $a$ and $c$ at a particular point of $x$ but I do not know the formula. For example I don't have something like $a(x) = x^2$. You feel me?

Comment: @Anonymous If $a$ and $c$ aren't defined then there's nothing more to say. What kind of answer do you want?

Comment: @avid19 it is defined. Like if I put $a(x)$ I get an output. But that output comes straight from an experimental data, in other words it is random. $a(x)$ is not something like $x^2$ or $x^2 + 5$ as we see in typical textbooks. I just have the data but I do not have the relation.

Comment: @Anonymous so your question is on numerical differentiation?

Comment: @Anonymous you can fit some sort of a curve to the data, or interpolate it with synthetic curves (like splines), and then apply the formulae above.